# Is there a WebAssembly interpreter for IE?

Tags: javascript, node.js, internet-explorer, virtual-machine, webassembly

I was wondering if there was a VM made in JS for older browsers to compute wasm.

Im not after speed/performance. Just overall compatibility.

Im not doing anything special just. 
Trying to run wasm across all browsers.

Comment: You could check [the Browser compatibility at mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly), IE has no support for WebAssembly. If you want to use the WebAssembly in your app, you could check the  "#[How do I use WebAssembly in my app?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Concepts)"

Comment: Yes, im well aware of that. Thats why I'm looking for an interpreter or VM I can use in IE. Like a translation layer i guess.

Answer (score 4):

[Webassemblyjs](https://github.com/xtuc/webassemblyjs/tree/master/packages/webassemblyjs) is a polyfill that runs WebAssemby modules within a JavaScript interpreter. However, the result is likely to be quite slow.

A better option, when using Emscripten, is to compile to [asm.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asm.js) for IE browsers. This option is better supported and likely to provide much better performance.

If your compiler toolchain does not support asm.js directly, the [BinaryEn](https://github.com/WebAssembly/binaryen) suite of tools includes `wasm2js` utility that compiles WebAssembly modules to an asm.js-like format.

Answer (score 0):

You might try [wasm-polyfill](https://github.com/rfk/wasm-polyfill), although it is no longer actively maintained